# CSS - Background lost after resizing window

Tags: css

I am working on the following website: `http://91.146.110.84/~pacspeop/`

I am nearing completion but have noticed that if you make the browser window smaller than the defined width of the container (960px) a scroll bar appears (as it should). However when you scroll to the right the header and footer loose any content.

Anyone any idea how I can resolve this?

Cheers

Comment: What browser are you using? did you try to test on other browsers?

Comment: its working fine at my end on chrome 20

Comment: It looks fine on FF to me, I tried making the window very thin and then scrolling sideways, the footer doesn't stretch to the width of content if thats what you mean? but surely thats just a situation to set the width of the footer to 100%

Comment: @AlaaBadran any browser: Chrome, Safari, Firefox all do the same.

Comment: @AndrewMorris The footer is already 100% - overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
height: 414px;
width: 100%;

Comment: Is that what you mean by the question though? that the width of the footer box isn't stretching? It looks like you're suggesting you are losing text content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey now do the body min width as like this

```
body{
min-width:960px;
}
```